The solution curves of Newton's differential equation are disjoint.
This problem is a continuation of my previous post The analytic continuition of the inverse of a complex polynomial., again from Smale's article about Alpha theory
Complexity on the Geometry of Polynomials and a Theory of Cost.
Let $f\in \mathbb{C}[z]$, $\xi_i\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\begin{cases}f(\xi_i)=0\\
f'(\xi_i)\neq 0 \end{cases} $. As in that post, we see that $f$ has an analytic compositional inverse $f_{\xi_i}^{-1}$ defined on $S_{\xi_i,f}$, which is the entire complex plane minus $k$ radial slits from (some minimal collection of the critical points $\theta_{i_1},\dots, \theta_{i_k}$) $f(\theta_{i_1}),\dots, f(\theta_{i_k})$ to $\infty$.
Here comes the question. The author want to show that the images of $f^{-1}_{\xi_i}$ are disjoint among the roots $\xi_i$. He argued by noticing that the image of a ray by $f_{\xi_i}^{-1}$, i.e.
$$ t\mapsto f_{\xi_i}^{-1}(ae^{-t}) $$
is a solution curve of the so-called Newton's differential equation
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}t}=-\frac{f(z)}{f'(z)}$$
in $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{C}$ which terminates at $\xi_i$. He said that these curves are disjoint among different roots $\xi_i$'s.
My question is: why does this argument work? I think it may be related to the (global) uniqueness of this ODE, but I haven't found any. Are there any theorems/ theories in ODE handy in this case?
Thanks in advance.

You may benefit from reading about Newton's method and the Newton fractal for the basins of attraction to each root.
